# Localization for the strings present in scripts

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, internationalization

I wish to translate my entire application into a different language. I have added a separate global resource project, which contains the resource file, LocalizableResources.resx. 
However i am stuck at the strings used within the javascripts, here is what i tried,

```
*var resourceDictionary = new ResourceReader(FILEPATH OR STREAM)
                                .Cast<DictionaryEntry>()
                                .Where(x=>x.Key.ToString().StartsWith("JS_"))
                                .ToDictionary(entry => entry.Key.ToString(), entry => entry.Value.ToString());
            var json = Serializer.Serialize(resourceDictionary);*
```

with all the javascript strings starting with "JS_".
The problem that i am facing is that i can't get the FILEPATH/STREAM, since the resource file is present as a different project (not within Web Endpoints). If anyone could provide a different way of doing it, or point out the mistake in this method, it'll be really helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you use any Javascript library like JQuery?
They have native feature or plugins for i18n.

About your code, you can use ResourceManager to retrieve all keys for your resources instead of directly access to resource files.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i used ResourceManager to retrieve all the keys, it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to define a variable containing the translations in the masterpage and use them in the .js files. See the following example for Razor:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var Translation = {
   helloWorld: '@MyResourceFile.HelloWorld',
   book: '@MyResourceFile.Book'
 }
</script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MyScriptFile.js")" type="text/javascript" />
```

Comment: This will work, but won't i have to add all the strings manually, and also when someone wishes to add more strings to the scripts they will have to modify at two places in order to use it, MyResourceFile and the master page.

Comment: True, in my case this was the most simple solution :)